# jQuery disabling input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some input elements on a page, and am trying to enable them or disable them according to the setting of a pair of radio buttons. I'm using the following Javascript function (console logging added for me to see what's going on)...

```
function EnableIndividualOrCompanyControls(individual) {
  console.log("EnableIndividualOrCompanyControls(" + individual + ")");
  console.log("Title value is " + $("#Title").val());
  console.log("Title was " + $("#Title").prop("disabled"));
  $("#Title").prop("disabled", !individual);
  console.log("Title is now " + $("#Title").prop("disabled"));
  console.log(" ");
  $("#Surname").prop("disabled", !individual);
  $("#CompanyName").prop("disabled", individual);
}
```

When the radio button value is changed, the method is getting called, and the parameter has the correct value, however the Title, Surname and CompanyName inputs are never disabled.

As sample from the console looks like this...

```
EnableIndividualOrCompanyControls(false)
Title value is Sir
Title was false
Title is now false
```

So, the function is being called, the parameter has the correct value, I am getting the Title input element correctly (as you can see from the fact that it correctly reports that its value is "Sir"), but the elements are not being disabled.

The odd thing is that I use exactly the same code elsewhere on the page, and it works fine. This function works...

```
function EnableOnlineControls(enable) {
  $("#UserName").prop("disabled", !enable);
  $("#Password").prop("disabled", !enable);
  $("#PasswordAgain").prop("disabled", !enable);
}
```

Anyone any idea why the first one doesn't work? In case it helps, here is the HTML for those form elements (surrounding divs removed for clarity)...

```
<input class="form-control" id="Title" name="Title" value="" />
<input class="form-control" id="Surname" name="Surname" value="" />
<input class="form-control" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" value="" />
```

I tried replacing the double quotes with single ones, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: I suggest that you build a fiddle, bacause on my machine, your code works.

Comment: OK, here goes... http://jsfiddle.net/g2ftjq8L/ - if you click the "Online access" checkbox, the user name and password controls are correctly enabled/disabled, but if you change the "individual/company" radio buttons, the title, first name, surname and company name controls don't change. Thx

Comment: Just noticed that the fiddle includes ArinCool's suggestion as well for one of the controls, but as you can see, neither approach works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [JQuery readOnly strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216987/jquery-readonly-strange-behavior/27217016#27217016) explains your problem.

`individual` comes from a checkbox; it is a string. You have to cast it properly to a boolean:

```
$("#Surname").prop("disabled", (individual == "false" ? false : true));
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. I was thinking that the values coming back were Boolean, which is why I was confused. Now I realise they are plain strings, it makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please upvote my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216987/jquery-readonly-strange-behavior/27217016#27217016 ? It has received -1 but I think it can be useful to other people

Comment: Just did. It's a very clear and helpful reply in my opinion. Explain one of the reason why I hate Javascript!