# JQuery readOnly strange behavior

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="test" ><br>
<button onclick="makeReadOnly('true')">Make read only (ok)</button>
<button onclick="makeReadOnly('false')">Make read/write (not ok)</button> 
<button onclick="makeReadOnly(false)">Make read/write (ok)</button>
```

with this script:

```
function makeReadOnly(r) {
    $("#test").prop("readOnly", r);
}
```

My problem is: call to `makeReadOnly(false)` works, while `makeReadOnly('false')` doesn't.

But `makeReadOnly('true')` works.

(tested with JQuery 1.9.1)

Who can explain me why ?

http://jsfiddle.net/ym9qe99p/1/

Comment: `'false'` string is truly, so makes it `true` when setting it using `.prop()` where second param should be a boolean for `readonly` property/attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of casting. The string `"false"` is cast as a Boolean `true`. Basically, any non-empty string is (along with 0 and a couple other things). Try it! `Boolean("false")`.

The `readOnly` property casts its input to a Boolean. Therefore both `"true"` and `"false"` become `true`, and only `false` stays `false`.