# "Disabled" input not disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a web page that uses HTML (CSS coming later, when the content and scripts are up and working), JavaScript and AJAX to manage a TShock server (for the game Terraria), using its REST API.

I want the page to support most, if not all, REST API endpoints (list available [here](https://tshock.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TSHOCKPLUGINS/REST+API+Endpoints)).

I currently have a problem with the [/v2/users/update](https://tshock.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TSHOCKPLUGINS/REST+API+Endpoints#RESTAPIEndpoints-/v2/users/update) endpoint's part. I want to create a form (without using the `<form>` tag, I don't want the chair-to-keyboard interface to screw up with the 'enter' key).

The endpoint's description says the optional fields are `password` and `group`. Not supplying at least one would defeat the point of updating the user.

To make sure that one or both was supplied, I wanted to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes (again because of the chair-to-keyboard interface).

Each radio button is supposed to enable the correct input fields, except they dont. Chrome's console doesn't report anything, as well as Firefox's and IE's.

Does anyone have an alternate solution for this ? Of course, I could have made a mistake.

I'd rather avoid changing a `div`'s `innerHTML` depending on the user's choice.

---

JS code (code sample using jQuery):

```
function PassInputOnly(){
    $.("#PwdField").prop("disabled", false); // Using document.getElementById("FieldId").disabled
    $.("#GrpField").prop("disabled", true); // doesn't work either.
}

function GrpInputOnly(){
    $.("#PwdField").prop("disabled", true);
    $.("#GrpField").prop("disabled", false);
}

function BothInputs(){
    $.("#PwdField").prop("disabled", false);
    $.("#GrpField").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="UpdUser" placeholder="Username">
<p>What will get updated ?</p>
<input type="radio" name="WhatGetsUpdated" onclick="BothInputs()" checked>Password and Group<br>
<input type="radio" name="WhatGetsUpdated" onclick="PassInputOnly()">Password<br>
<input type="radio" name="WhatGetsUpdated" onclick="GrpInputOnly()">Group<br>
<input type="text" id="PwdField" placeholder="New password">
<input type="text" id="GrpField" placeholder="New group">
```

Note: it is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215381/jquery-disabling-input-not-working), though I want to use `on*` events, not values.

Comment: `$.("#PwdField")` should be `$("#PwdField")`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "." after $ i.e

```
$.("#PwdField") ==> $("#PwdField")
```

Check this out :

```js
function PassInputOnly(){
 
    $("#PwdField").prop("disabled", false); // Using document.getElementById("FieldId").disabled
    $("#GrpField").prop("disabled", true); // doesn't work either.
}

function GrpInputOnly(){
    $("#PwdField").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#GrpField").prop("disabled", false);
}

function BothInputs(){
    $("#PwdField").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#GrpField").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="UpdUser" placeholder="Username">
<p>What will get updated ?</p>
<input type="radio" name="WhatGetsUpdated" onclick="BothInputs()" checked>Password and Group<br>
<input type="radio" name="WhatGetsUpdated" onclick="javascript:PassInputOnly()">Password<br>
<input type="radio" name="WhatGetsUpdated" onclick="GrpInputOnly()">Group<br>
<input type="text" id="PwdField" placeholder="New password">
<input type="text" id="GrpField" placeholder="New group">
```